# Oracle DB - getting same sequence values across different Environments?

Tags: oracle

How to create sequences so that the value remains same across different environment?

I have created a package with procedures and functions in it, which takes data from staging tables and inserts into production schema( it's a copy of production schema).

The problem is the tables in the production have primary key as sequence and some other columns combination for each table.

I am generating sequence values through a function that I wrote with some initial values that were available at that time. Each table has a separate sequence created. Now I have to deploy same stuff in different environments(UAT,preprod etc) before its done in the production.

I want the values to be generated as same that have been generated or will be generated across all environments.  How can I achieve that, instead of giving initial values for a sequence, have the values dynamic?

Comment: This can't be done. The values generated by a sequence are meaningless and should never be relied upon. You need to structure your scripts so that they don't rely on specific values (but use e.g. `currval` to reference that last generated value)

Comment: Why do you care about the values of surrogate keys? Do these tables contain reference data or lookup codes?

Comment: The tables are not referential.

Comment: The tables are not referential on primary keys etc. The tables can be joined based on ID columns when querying data. Basically there are two main Tables forexample, Table 1 and Table 2. The Table 1 Primary Key = (surrogate_id,version_number). Table 2 primary key = surrogate_id,version_number). there is  Table1_ID column in Table1. Table2_ID and Table2_ID column in Table2.  Same columns are present in rest of the tables. So when quering data, we only select data based on joins Table1_ID and Table2_ID columns. Surrogate_id is not used for joins.